# I cant sculpt with dyntopo

Tags: modeling, sculpting, error, dynamic-topology

I'm using blender 2.8 and when I tried to sculpting there's no change in my object. In the video I watched, he was able to do it with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key without turning on the dyntopo.

It didn't happen when I tried, so I tried to open it up. But even if I opened the dyntopo, I couldn't make any changes to the surface of the object.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackExchange. It would be helpful if you could show a screenshot or post the file itself. Just a random guess, but you may not have the object selected when switching to the sculpting workspace. Go to the *Layout* tab, select the object making sure it is highlighted in yellow, then return back to the *Sculpting* workspace.

Comment: Try Reading this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157741/sculpting-brushes-behaves-weird
might help you.